# How to get the cartesian form of a plan from its Hesse form?

Tags: vectors, plane-geometry, point-cloud

This [class](https://github.com/stetro/project-tango-poc/blob/master/ar/src/main/java/de/stetro/master/ar/calc/RANSAC.java) provides the necessary tools to find a plane in a point cloud using the RANSAC algorithm; the plane is defined in Hesse normal form, meaning that it returns an array of four cells: the first three cells correspond to the three components of the normal vector of the plane ($ \vec{n} = [ x, y, z ] $) and the fourth one is the distance of the plane from the origin. How can I use that result to get the equation of the plane under the form $ ax + by + cz - d = 0 $ ? Otherwise, how could I tell if a point belongs to the plane while in Hesse form? Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: How did you defined the Hessian form?

Comment: I did not define it, the algorithm is not mine. But the only information it returns about a plane is the normal to the plane and the distance of the plane from the origin. The author calls this "hessian form".

Comment: $\vec n\cdot\vec x=d\vec n$.

Comment: what is $\vec{x}$ ?

Comment: nevermind, I think I got it: $\vec{x}$ is the vector whose components are the coordinates of the point whose distance to the plane I want to know.